# Problem with Docx editor within my web app(seeking high flexibilitty) / Google Docs API getter that returns a position of user's cursor?

Tags: ms-word, google-docs, docx, google-docs-api, docxtemplater

I have an app focused on automation of administrative processes. It works thanks to **docx** templates mapped to some fields inside my db.
Example:

- Mapped document: Dear **`{client.firstName} {client.lastName}`**, we are pleased to offer you a job as a **`{client.appliedForJobRole}`**
- Result: Dear **John Doe**, we are pleased to offer you a job as a **janitor**.

I'm trying to implement a document mapping technology within my app so mapping the templates by employees wouldn't be a total headache for them.

My expectations of how the document mapper should look like:
[image]

The flow should be like this:

1. I place cursor/click somewhere inside the docx.
2. After that - a dropdown opens up and I'm able to select a field from my database.
3. After selecting the field a placeholder in format **`{fieldName}`** would be placed at the position of where I had initially clicked.
4. Bonus feature: If it's possible, I want to be able to show **`Field Verbose Value`** instead of **`{fieldValue}`** with proper styling(as seen in the picture) - only on client side. The actual docx will still have **`{fieldValue}`**

The functionality doesn't have to be exactly like shown in the picture - it's just for reference so you know what I want to achieve.

**My tech stack:**

- Vue
- Fast API that uses LibreOffice(necessary conversions) and docxtemplater(exchanging placeholders for actual values inside the .docx)

**What I tried so far ?**

**Solution WYSIWYG editor + conversions**
I tried to use WYSIWYG editor(Quill) with conversions using both LibreOffice and Mammoth.js - DOCX->HTML(Import) and HTML->DOCX(Export)

- **Result** These conversions were Ok when I was converting some really basic documents. Results from more complex documents weren't really satisfying. That's why I abandoned this idea.

**Solution OnlyOffice**
Using full fledged DOCX web editor - OnlyOffice.

- **Result** I couldn't find a way on how to edit UI of Onlyoffice nor I couldn't find out how to programatically change content of DOCX.

**Solution Google Docs API**
Using full fledged DOCX web editor - Google Docs API.

- **My findings** This one looks the most promising as Google Workspace provides App Scripts where I can define my own functionality to some extend. I went trough the documentation and found out that it may be a problem to retrieve client's cursor position.

**My questions**

- First question is aimed at the ones who worked with the Google Docs API - Do you see a way on how to achieve this functionality using mentioned Google's platform ? Does Google Docs API provide a way to track user's actions(click in editor) so I can react to them(extract position of click so I can place there a new text(**`{fieldValue}`**) according to field chosen from the dropdown(I saw that you can add custom UI element in toolbar)) ?
- Second question - Do you know any library or platform that would suit my needs more appropriately ? Or maybe do you see a way on how to implement this value/feature more efficiently ?

I want to know other developer's perspective before I start to implement this feature so thanks for any response.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between Microsoft Word (DOCX) and Google Document. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hello - I want to use google docs api to implement docx editor within browser. So anyone can map their document without the need of leaving my app/leaving browser.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Basically I’m just trying to find someone who built smth like this in the past(the mapper from screenshot) and tells me if I’m wasting time with google docs or it fits my needs. My biggest concern with google docs is the part, when user needs to define where he wants to add the placeholder - e.g. he clicks somewhere in the editor, cursor position will be extracted(is this possible with google docs ?), dropdown will show up with all the choices from db, he selects one of the choices and {choiceValue} will be written on the spot where he clicked. Do you think that it is possible w google docs ?